Update values from a column of one table if they exist in another table's column if these values are unique
I have a column filled with values that need updating because they are too ambiguous and I want to update these values with values from another table columns.
Player Table:



ID
Email
FirstName




1
Bob.Lance@gmail.com
Bob


2
Laura.Davis@gmail.com
Laura


3
Josh.Stevens@gmail.com
Josh


4
Alex.Wild@gmail.com
Alex


5
Bob.Frank@gmail.com
Bob


6
Alex.Summers@gmail.com
Alex



Sports Table:



Sport
Players




Golf
Laura


Basketball
Josh


Baseball
Alex


Football
Bob


Volleyball
Laura


Swimming
Alex


Driving
Bob


Boxing
Bob



In this example I am trying to replace values in the Players column with the player's Email because some players have the same first name. I don't believe that there is a way to find out which Bob and Alex are in the Sports Table so I want to do the minimum and change the column values for the names do not have duplicate first names. The updated Sports Table should look like below.
Updated Sports Table:



Sport
Player




Golf
Laura.Davis@gmail.com


Basketball
Josh.Stevens@gmail.com


Baseball
Alex


Football
Bob


Volleyball
Laura.Davis@gmail.com


Swimming
Alex


Driving
Bob


Boxing
Bob



My first thought was to find all column values in the Player table that did not have any First Names that showed up more than once and I managed to get that far with the following query below.
SELECT Email, FirstName
FROM PlayerTable
GROUP BY Email, FirstName
HAVING COUNT(P.FirstName) = 1

However, I haven't been able to find a way to use this to update the Sports Table correctly. I tried the following lines of code, but that just outputted an incorrect table.
UPDATE SportsTable
SET Player = (
    SELECT P.Email, P.FirstName
    FROM PlayerTable P
    WHERE P.FirstName = Player
    GROUP BY P.Email, P.FirstName
    HAVING COUNT(P.FirstName) = 1
)


Sorry for the image of the first table. For some reason I could not submit my question without the first table throwing an error for some reason.

@Dale: For some reason it is seeing the next rows of the table as a code snippet and kept on saying I could not save my edit without solving the syntax errors. And since the problem was not originating from a code snippet, but instead a table, I could not add to the first table.

I still can't modify the rows. I attached an image of the error in the question.

Yes, that is correct! Thank you very much.

You are basically on the right track.
This query will return all First Names and their email that appear with one email only:
SELECT 
  FirstName,
  MIN(Email) AS Email
FROM Player
GROUP BY 
  FirstName
HAVING 
  COUNT(DISTINCT Email) = 1;

So you need to check the distinct count of emails per FirstName rather than count the FirstName itself.
You can use above query in a CTE or in a pure subquery and join it to the Sports table. I think both ways are fine.
Here the option with a CTE:
WITH uniqueMails AS
(SELECT 
  FirstName,
  MIN(Email) AS Email
FROM Player
GROUP BY 
  FirstName
HAVING 
  COUNT(DISTINCT Email) = 1)
UPDATE s
SET s.Players = u.Email
FROM Sport s
JOIN uniqueMails u
ON s.Players = u.FirstName;

Verify it works as expected on this db<>fiddle with your sample data.
And here the option without CTE:
UPDATE s
SET s.Players = uniqueMails.Email
FROM Sport s
JOIN 
(SELECT 
  FirstName,
  MIN(Email) AS Email
FROM Player
GROUP BY 
  FirstName
HAVING 
  COUNT(DISTINCT Email) = 1) uniqueMails
ON s.Players = uniqueMails.FirstName;

db<>fiddle for this option.

It also works with two simple subselects
UPDATE SportsTable 
   SET Player = (select Email from PlayerTable p where p.FirstName = Player) 
   where (select count(*) from PlayerTable p where p.FirstName = Player) = 1 

